# Sequelize: Joining Many to Many tag table with another table in postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to setup many to many relationship in Sequelize for my Postgres tables using a tag (lookup) table. I was successful in setting up the relationship.

Now my lookup table, has an additional field which is a foreign key to another table. I want the data for that table to be included in my result set. This is where I am having hard time figuring out the syntax.

My models:

```
Models.user = sequelize.define('user', { //attributes});
Models.school = sequelize.define('school', { //attributes });
Models.role = sequelize.define('role', { //attributes });

Models.userSchools = sequelize.define('user_school', {
    user_school_id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true }
});

Models.user.belongsToMany(Models.school, { through: Models.userSchools, foreignKey: 'user_id', otherKey: 'school_id' });
Models.school.belongsToMany(Models.user, { through: Models.userSchools, foreignKey: 'school_id', otherKey: 'user_id' });
Models.userSchools.belongsTo(Models.role, { foreignKey: 'role_id' });
```

Working query: This query gives me all the users and their schools.

```
Models.user.findAll({
            where: {
                //condition
            },
            include: [Models.school]
        })
```

Now I want to include the role for each schools. None of the below queries are working.

```
Models.user.findAll({
            where: {
                //conditions
            },
            include: [Models.schools, Models.role]
        })
```

Above query is throwing an error saying role is not associated to user, which is expected.

```
Models.user.findAll({
            where: {
                //conditions
            },
            include: [Models.schools, {model: Models.userSchools, include: Models.role}]
        })
```

This query is also throwing an error:

> "userSchools is not associated to user".

Can any one help with syntax to how I can get the role information from the userSchools model?

### Edit:

I have add a "through" condition which gets me the role_id but not the related role data.

```
Models.user.findAll({
        where: {
            //conditions
        },
        include: [{
            model: Models.school,
            as: 'schools',
            through: {
                attributes: ['role_id']
            }
        }]
    })
```

Comment: have you tried `through`? ```Models.user.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Models.schools,
    include: [{

    }],
    through: {
      attributes: [// define your through attributes]
    }
  }]
})``` (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html)

Comment: @mcranston18 I have tried that, it gives me role_id from the lookup table but not the role data from "role" table. I have updated my questions. See Edit. Thank you

Comment: you might need to add a nested include ```Models.user.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Models.schools,
    include: [Model.role],
  }] 
})```

Comment: I tried that too. It throws an error saying school is not related to role as there is no direct relationship from school to role.

Comment: @user3731783 did you ever get a solution for this? I'm having the same problem. Thanks in advance